# GitLab - Disable 2FA for only one user in an organizaiton

Tags: gitlab, two-factor-authentication

2FA authentication is enabled in our organization, meaning any user who logs into GitLab is prompted with 2FA. Recently, we had to create a Service Account for various business reasons. How could we disable 2FA only for the Service Account user.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to deactivate 2FA for a user, make sure that user has a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)

As explained in "[Use personal access tokens with two-factor authentication](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/account/two_factor_authentication.html#use-personal-access-tokens-with-two-factor-authentication)"

> When 2FA is enabled, you can’t use your password to authenticate with Git over HTTPS or the GitLab API.
> You can use a personal access token instead.

Using the PAT as password allows the user to bypass the 2FA step.

Considering GitLab, and the [access to `npm` registry](https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/packages/npm_registry.md#authenticating-to-the-gitlab-npm-registry), as per [issue 9140](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ee/issues/9140), this (using a PAT) is <del>not yet supported (Apr. 2022)</del>.

That meant (before issue resolution) you has to use a dedicated account without 2FA, possibly from a *different organization* which would exist solely for:

- hosting service accounts
- without 2FA (since 2FA would not be mandatory in that second organization)

That was certainly a workaround, but one which would allow you to wait for the resolution of the aforementioned GitLab issue.

However, **the issue was resolved for GitLab 12.2** (Aug. 20219).
See "[npm packages in the Package Registry  / Authenticate with a personal access token or deploy token](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/npm_registry/#authenticate-with-a-personal-access-token-or-deploy-token)".

---

Furthermore, with [GitLab 15.2](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/07/22/gitlab-15-2-released/#audit-events-when-two-factor-authentication-is-disabled) (July 2022), you can make sure everybody does have 2FA.

> ### Audit events when two-factor authentication is disabled
>
> GitLab now records an audit event when a user disables their two-factor authentication (2FA) settings.
>
> This audit event helps you ensure that all the users in your instance are properly using
> 2FA (and identify when the security of a user’s account has been lowered),
> so that you can investigate and take action.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/audit_events.html#instance-events) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/238177).

Comment: Yes, this works in most of the use cases needing a Service Account; however I'm trying to utilize the built-in NPM package manager feature of GitLab, and it says that authentication cannot be done by a 2FA enabled account or PAT; https://gitlab.com/help/user/project/packages/npm_registry.md#authenticating-to-the-gitlab-npm-registry

Comment: @ThomasJoseph Right, good point. I have edited the answer to propose a workaround, but there does not seem to be a natively-supported solution.

Comment: It's a bit odd that your answer mentions GitHub in a quote, because that's not GitLab.

Comment: @mbomb007 Good point thank you for the feedback. I have rewritten the beginning of the answer to reference GitLab documentation, not GitHub. (even though the idea and principle remain the same)